# Getting this error while building angular>14 project

Tags: angular, webpack

[image]

Getting this error in my angular 14
already  checked this command in powershell
**node --max-old-space-size=10240 index.js**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it includes pictures of the error rather than a text representation. Links to pictures eventually expire, which will render the question useless to future readers.

Comment: instead of index.js you should use node  ng build or better to create a script